# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED when adding another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to add a second activity to my android manifest file but am receiving a INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED error. I have isolated the offending code to this line:

```
    <activity android:name="com.MyPackage.Main.FacebookLoginActivity" 
        android:label="Facebook"></activity>
```

When I type it in like this

```
    <activity android:name=".FacebookLoginActivity" 
        android:label="Facebook"></activity>
```

it works fine but when I try to start the activity via

```
this.startActivity(new Intent(this, FacebookLoginActivity.class));
```

I get an error saying cannot locate "com.MyPackage.Main/com.MyPackage.Main.FacebookLoginActivity".

Is that activity wrong in some way?

Here a portion of my manifest file:

```
<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:allowBackup="true">        
    <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@style/Theme.NoBackground">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
   </activity> 

    <activity android:name="com.MyPackage.Main.FacebookLoginActivity" android:label="Facebook"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
              android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" 
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

</application>
```

Comment: Check your package name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing you package declaration to com.mypackage.main.
Your class name would be com.mypackage.main.FacebookLoginActivity